# Magento shopping cart rule for paypal checkout?

Tags: magento, paypal

I would like to add a 5% OFF discount for those customer who're paid with Paypal. Please advice how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Magento Backend, go to `promotions -> shopping cart price rules -> add new rule`.
- Conditions tab: set this to `payment method` is `credit card` (under paypal heading).
- If you use more paypal methods, add them the same way.
- Actions tab: set Apply to `Percent of product price discount` and set Disocunt Amount to `5`.

That's it.

Comment: Hi, According to your advice, all settings are done. However the price does not changed with the 5% discount. Can you let me know what is possible wrong? See detailed screen shots above in the original question.

Comment: Did you flush cache? Unfortunately, I don't see any screenshots.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did plus reindexing too. Try this link where you can review the screenshots. http://www.thebodyshop.ie/info-page/

Comment: On `rule information` tab, only theConcessionStore is selected for `website`. Select also theBodyShopIreland and save and try again.

Comment: I tried with both options(both stores), but no discount applied. Nothing changed, still does not applying the 5% off.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the same website.

And try to change end date. Don't select same starting date and ending date.

After Save Rule.

Go to Promotions >> Catalog Price Rules

Click on Apply Rules and check it.

Cheers :)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. Where should I see the 5% off, is it should be displayed on the Paypal page after redirected to there?

Comment: when you redirect back your site, you will see the order review where you can find all the order and discount details